# How does iAd choose ads based on the country?

Tags: ios, iad, storekit, ip-geolocation

There's a list of countries where iAds are available, but how do I check if the user's device is in that country?

In particular, does iAd choose ads based on the country:

- The device was bought in?
- The App Store the app was downloaded from (based on StoreKit receipts perhaps)?
- The current physical location of the device (presumably based on its IP address)?

I'd like to enable or disable certain non-iAD functionality based on whether iAd is available in that country.

Comment: Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684863/displaying-ios-iads-only-to-supported-countries

Comment: You could simply have two versions of the app and make them available in different countries.

Comment: Why not use another ad network when iAd is not available?

Answer (score 1):

iAd choose ads based on the user The current physical location of the device. Apple tracks user location and ads more based on location + interest + type of application (your app).
User can disable location based iAd from [settings](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT202074).

For more details you can also see [this guide](http://advertising.apple.com) for advertiser although not for the developers but give you better idea how apple advertise.