# Is there a way to get the current NSLocaleCountryCode of the user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

I am currently getting the *NSLocaleCountryCode* by 
 `NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];` Now, the problem is if the iPhone or iPad is bought from a certain country and the user moves into a different country. The NSLocaleCountryCode returns the value of the country where the device is bought. Is there a way to get the *Current* NSLocaleCountryCode?

Comment: The `NSLocaleCountryCode` has nothing to do with where the device was purchased or where it is currently located. It is based on the setting in the Settings app for General, Language & Region, Region.

Comment: What do you mean by the "current" country code? What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: @rmaddy For example, the device is bought in US. So the NSLocaleCountryCode is set to US right? Then the user moves to another country say Canada. And I am trying to get CA, the "current" country code of the phone

Comment: Without the user changing his/her Region in the settings. Should I use different function?

Comment: You are still being unclear. Do you want to know the country that the device is physically in at the moment? If so, use Core Location and get the user's current location (If the user allows your app to do so).

Answer (score 3):

`NSLocale` is just a setting about currently used regional settings, it doesn't mean the actual country you're in.

Use `CLLocationManager` to get current location and use  `CLGeocoder` to perform reverse-geocoding. You can get country name from `CLGeocoder`.

if you need the additional help see this [alternate way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940615/find-current-country-from-iphone-device)

**Updated answer**

```
 CLGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation    completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
// NSLog(@"Received placemarks: %@", placemarks);

CLPlacemark *myPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *countryCode = myPlacemark.ISOcountryCode;
NSString *countryName = myPlacemark.country;
NSString *cityName= myPlacemark.subAdministrativeArea;
NSLog(@"My country code: %@ and countryName: %@ MyCity: %@", countryCode, countryName, cityName);
```

Comment: @drbj - check the updated answer, and sample link https://ktrkathir.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/get-city-country-name-from-latitudelongitude-by-using-clgeocoder-in-ios/

Comment: Where does newLocation came from?

Comment: @drbj - using CLLOcation Manager u get the location using `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations`

Comment: I think I am missing import or so, expected a type error.

Comment: cna you updated the question once bro, I think you confused little bit

Comment: See my reply to @rmaddy's comment bro. Thanks!

Comment: correct bro , but `NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];` not given update loaction bro

Comment: I see, so what should i use then to get the updated location?